# Navigation displaying slightly different in Firefox

Tags: html, css

On a site I'm working on, I've got everything looking pretty much the same over the **main** browsers (checking Chrome, Safari & Firefox).

All except for a pesky 1px gap on the navigation items, noticeable on the **active** items (when the background is filled).

You can visit the site here: http://lumbre.breadadams.com/

This is the gap I'm talking about

[image: 1px menu item space]

I've messed about with `height`, `line-height`, `padding`, etc. of multiple elements (nav, ul and such), but nothing seems to do the trick.

However if I increase `font-size` from `1.2em` to `1.3em` it fits, but then it doesn't on Chrome. Increasing the font `0.1` at a time makes it alternate between fitting on Chrome and Firefox basically.

Comment: Could you post the relevant markup and CSS?

Comment: Sure http://codebin.org/view/8f353a1d (ah it's written in Sass - .scss - format btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#navigation-container #main-nav ul > li.menu-item-has-children > a::after {
    content: "";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    margin-left: 4px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Here is your answer amigo!

Just add a `position: absolute;`

it's the `:after`   (the small icon) that needs a position absolute. It's causing a bit of upper space, but when you give it a position absolute, all is good my friend!

Comment: Try to preferably use position absolute when using :before or :after, so you can place it exactly where you want. Most of the time what we put in :before or :after is something small anyway and we want to place it pixel perfect somewhere,, and position absolute helps us a lot with this ;)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't use this **exact** solution, but you're right on the whole `position: absolute;` thing. I added the caret icon to a :before on the `li`, and gave those `position: relative;`. But yeah, it's working now - cheers :)